# How to find the entry point in LLDB on OS X?

Tags: osx, lldb, entry-point

How can I identify the entry point of an executable in LLDB?

In GDB, we can use the `info file` command, but that won't work in LLDB.

Can anyone show me how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of the command

```
(lldb) process launch --stop-at-entry
```

to start the program. This stops you right at the entry point. From there lldb will tell you the address as well, in case this is what you are interested in.

If instead you were interested in the actual main function, and not the entry point, you should have a look at the related question [lldb: break at start of actual code, not entrypoint](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6719/lldb-break-at-start-of-actual-code-not-entrypoint)

Comment: What is the difference between `--stop-at-entry` and breaking at `__libc_start_main`?

Comment: @JAL: see https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/19572/60. BTW, `__libc_start_main` is not used on OS X (it's a glibc thing)