# Is the value of EBP before the main function important?

Tags: x86, memory, buffer-overflow, stack, register

So before we come to the main function, it looks we are in a function with a name __libc_start_main

and before we come to our main function we obviously push EBP value in the stack ( the value of EBP before main function, in the __libc_start_main function)

so first off is this value important? after the execution of main function, will the __libc_start_main function need this value?

is there any function that gets called before __libc_start_main therefore making this EBP value important?

i tested it and even if i overwrite this value(in the stack) with overflowing, the program finishes with no problem but i don't get how and why? shouldn't it result in error or page fault?

Comment: All general-purpose registers are zeroed by the Linux loader before the program starts executing, which gets passed to __libc_start_main I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__libc_start_main` is called by the *entry point code* (usually in a file called `crt0.S` or similar) and *that* code usually sets up the initial `EBP` value (usually to 0, to denote end of the call stack for the debuggers). Here's a sample entry point code from a random ELF binary:

```
_start:
     xor     ebp, ebp
     pop     esi
     mov     ecx, esp
     and     esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
     push    eax
     push    esp             ; stack_end
     push    edx             ; rtld_fini
     push    offset __libc_csu_fini ; fini
     push    offset __libc_csu_init ; init
     push    ecx             ; ubp_av
     push    esi             ; argc
     push    offset main     ; main
     call    ___libc_start_main
     hlt
```

While `__libc_start_main` itself *could* initialize `EBP` to 0, this would make it appear as if it's the first code in the binary when looking at the call stack, which is not correct (the execution begins at `_start`, the entry point).

Besides, `__libc_start_main`  can be (and often is) written in C instead of assembly, and it's easier for the compiler to generate the standard prolog code for it instead of making some kind of special case exception.

As for overwriting the value, you don't get a crash because:

1. `ebp` is not actually used by the caller of `___libc_start_main` (the entry point code)
2. `___libc_start_main` does not actually return, since it calls `exit()` with the return value of `main()` to directly exit to the OS, so your corrupted `ebp` does not matter

In the unlikely event that `___libc_start_main` does return (e.g. due to a bug in libc), the entry point code will execute the `hlt` instruction which is privileged so the process will be killed by the OS.

Comment: One question, why in the wikipedia of crt0, in the code for x86_64 the entry code directly calls main instead of __libc_start_main? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0

Comment: It depends on the specific compiler/toolchain/libc used. __libc_start_main can perform additional tasks before or after calling main, but in some cases you don’t really need them

Comment: so overall if we have _libc_start_main, the order of execution is crt0 -> _libc_start_main -> main, correct?